# How to execute a script at the start and end of every application in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am trying to log the applications that a user opens/closes in the Linux (any distro) OS. Is there a way to execute a script (Java,Python,etc) everytime an application (like firefox,etc) is opened and closed?

Comment: So, what have you been working on?  Have you tried Shell Scripts, Or what?

Comment: what i know is every process forks from init (or its children).. So i am wondering how i could exploit that fact to run a small logging script before the fork and after the process has been destroyed.

Comment: You know that hundreds upon thousands of applications/ executables execute regularly, including maintence apps etc.  Im not sure if your goal is to log EVERY applcation or certain ones.

Comment: Yes I am aware. Like i specified, i'd like to go behind the ones that the USER opens... Like browsers, text editors, media players..

Comment: Ahh, so this would be a root-injected set of scripts to monitor a particular group or user.  Thats a little bit more feasible, i feel.  I feel that @User1836386 is the NSA. :-D

Comment: Noooo! Using it to detect patterns of application usage to make better the memory management! :O
Please tell me how do i go about it?

Comment: To me, This is a multi-part question.  1)  Create a script which will run when the user logs in.  `source myscript.sh &` will run it.  Then inside this script, it would just read the processes running for the particular user: (use the `ps`) command, and pip the unique ids, and names into a database.  Then if they are no longer visible with `ps` they wouldve died and you could stop the timer.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! I must explore! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general feature -- no.

The execution of a script to log the execution, would in itself be a program execution which would require logging, and hence you would have a recursive problem.

However, if you want to log specific programs, you can implement a shell script which replaces the executable for those specific programs (firefox, python etc), and then within that shell script you could log the execution before calling the actual program.

However

1. The user would still be able to call the original program without the logging if they know the path.
2. The new scripts would be a security issue (making the system less secure) and hence would not be recommended.

So in short, a bad idea.

Comment: +1 because of the recursive nature of the problem.  Not sure what will be run, but it would be run every time the app would run and chew up all the memory pretty quick

Comment: Yes i thought of that. But like you said, not foolproof.
Anyway i could use what the "pstree" command might be using?
or adding something to the init itself (is that possible?)

Comment: init is just a program (may now be somewhat special program, but just a program) which forks processes -- there is no magic there.   pstree just get data from /proc and/or /sys which is a read only -- sure you can monitor that, but there is no guarantee that you will be sufficiently fast to see all programs which exists only for a split second -- and you will see your own log program in there as well.

Comment: but while forking i am sure some fork() function might be called. Anyway i could edit that function? add a few lines of my own before whatever not-magic it does?

Comment: `fork` is a operating system call you can modify the operating system yourself by downloading the source code and building a new kernel -- however the functional call  you would want is `exec`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question, but still.

You can actually do this. See https://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux

There are many answers. For example, you could use [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd).